# Can't use remote-ssh extention of vscode in my shared web hosting plan

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, ssh, ovh, vscode-remote-ssh

I've been trying to connect to my ssh using the VS Code extention "Remote SSH", I edited the config file just like i've done it previously but this time, it doesn't work.

this is the error i'm getting:

[error code in visual studio code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wNuN.png)

and this is what the console looks like:

[console logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTotz.png)

it says in the last line that i should change AllowTcpForwarding in sshd_config but i don't have access to that (i don't think) when using a shared web hoster like OVH.

i wonder if it's even doable to have access to my files via this VS code extention or i should just give it up?

please note that the ssh connexion via terminal does work. it's with the VS code extention that i'm having this issue.

i have tried adding 'AllowTcpForwarding yes' to the config file, tried to access the sshd_config file from console but it didn't work because of permissions.

i have also tried deleting .vscode-server folder and connecting again.